# class QToolButton’ has no member named ‘setToolTipDuration’

Tags: qt

I have set tool tip duration for tool buttons in the designer mode of Qt Creator. The application runs decently in Qt Creator.

But when I run the same application in terminal command using make followed by usage of qmake command, I get the following errors associated with each tool button I have added in the designer mode:

```
ui_mainwindow.h:377:22: error: ‘class QToolButton’ has no member named ‘setToolTipDuration’ pointButton->setToolTipDuration(200000);
```

Why is the above error displayed when using make command? How do I make it working with make command as well?

Answer (score 5):

from  Qt help:

> toolTipDuration : int
>
> This property was introduced in Qt 5.2.

Probably you have installed Qt in you OS with version below the 5.2